# Get user information using access_tokens (not using facebook APIs)

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have successfull requested an access_token through manual login system construction. Please keep in mind I'm not using **facebook php login API** or **javascript SDK**. In the access token I asked permission to obtain the public profile and user_friends who also use my app. I have obtained public information using `file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/me?$access_token");` and I got the profile link, the name, the gender, etc, but how can I obtain the user_friends as mentioned above and how exactly do I manage [context](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/social-context/v2.1) with the access token to obtain those informations? I don't understand how to use **context** with the file_get_contents above too...

Comment: You are aware that /me/friends will only return friends that are using the app. So it could be that you are doing things correct it is just that you don't have any friends that are using the app

Comment: So file get contents how it is now would return friends if there would be any?

Comment: No you are doing a request to /me that doesn't return any friends. Do a request to /me/friends